# SharePoint list emails users without using workflow (apparently); need to change email address forwarded to

Tags: 2013, list, infopath, email

I've inherited a site in SP 2013 that has a list that accepts incoming emails.  When a new item is added to this list, SharePoint sends an email to a particular user.  If people sent an email to xyz@company.com, then it would create an item in this list.  Then, a particular user is forwarded an email with the summary of the list item, with the notification that the email came from xyz@company.com (and I am trying to change which user this email gets sent to once something is posted to this list).

I've looked at the incoming email settings for this list, and I am not really sure how / why this list is emailing *out* to begin with.  I see that it would accept email but I don't see how it is emailing another (there are no SharePoint workflows associated with this list at all, and the list is set to not save any incoming emails either, by the way).

Maybe there is something I am missing in Outlook or Exchange settings?  or is it possible that this was done somehow in an Infopath form -- something like the email gets sent to that email address to create a list item, then that populates the Infopath form, and that somehow sends an email with the same 'from: xyz@company.com'.

Comment: Check with SharePoint Designer for a Workflow that sends an Email when a condition is met.

Comment: Thanks David.  I've looked at the workflows for the entire site but it looks like it was the alert me function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Alerts are turned on for the list. You can check the subscriptions by going to the Manage Alerts page. You can navigate there by going to:

**Site Settings > Site Administration > User Alerts**

The address though is just **YOURSITEURL/_layouts/15/sitesubs.aspx**